# Deep Learning - How to prepare the training data for large classification set?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, text-classification

So I have a large set of classes (say 500 for now, which might grow over time). These classes can be thought of as different domain specific rules.

Each rule has specific kind of testing associated with it. My data is like this:

```
Some text regarding Rule 1 ------> Rule 1
Some other text for Rule 1 ------> Rule 1
Some other other text for Rule 1 -----> Rule 1

Text regarding Rule 2 ----> Rule 2
Some other text regarding Rule 2 ----> Rule 2
```

You get an idea. I have a lot of text which I need to classify into Rules. One approach that I started with is using `one hot encoded form` of data as the Rule classification.

These are the steps I followed :

```
1. Create a Lexicon with all my Rule texts.
2. Create an array of 0s(of size of lexicon) for each line of text and turn on the index when the word is in lexicon.
3. Create a one hot encoded array (size = length(Rules)) with the index corresponding to Rule set to 1.
4. Feed this data to TensorFlow.
5. Test it out. I get prediction vector of size = length(Rules), 
   which gives me 1 for the index corresponding to the Rule the text was classified 
   into. I used tf.argmax()
```

This works well so far. My question is, if this approach is valid when the class size grows to 1000, ten thousand classes and so on. Do I still need to pass one hot encoded vector as the actual classification?

Is there an alternate way ?

Comment: Do you intend to retrain model from scratch each time a new class is added or would you like to 'extend' already trained model to new rules? Because these are 2 entirely different tasks and the later one is a lot less studied

Comment: @yauheni_selivonchyk I can retrain model from scratch each time a new class is added (since this would be an infrequent operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classification tasks of 1000 (4000, if you consider full ILSVRC dataset) classes are pretty common in image recognition ([ILSVRC](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks)) and proved to be working pretty well given enough training data.

Even so, at least one of the papers showed noticeable (97% -> 95%, maybe) decrease in classification accuracy going from 1K to 4K classes on ILSVRC data using the same model design.

Face recognition research [provides an example](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/pdf/YiSun_CVPR14.pdf) where increasing the number of classes (and number of training examples alongside) actually causes increase in classification accuracy. They test it on up to 10000 distinct classes.

If you make it over 10K it would be a time for you to write a paper of your own.

### One-hot encoding

Syntactic sugar as below might help you avoid building one-hot vectors by hand, but essentially one hot vectors would still be present as an input of cross-entropy loss function.
Syntactic sugar:

```
tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
```

Or

```
def to_one_hot(index, num_classes):
  res = np.zeros(num_classes)
  res[index] = 1
  return res
```

One-hot vector is used in cross-entropy loss to calculate classification error. Beauty of using sparse vectors is that even if a training example has been classified correctly by output [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1] -> 0  it still allows to produce cross-entropy error with vector [1.0, 0., 0., 0.]. This allows to have a gradient update even while there is no improvement of classification accuracy (i.e. training classification error is small <1% and plain classification error would produce gradients only on 1 example out of 100 or less).

You can always apply more labor and perform clustering of the inputs and train  a classifier for each cluster and what not. It might or might not work for you. Here is an example where alike approach actually improved accuracy [link](http://vision.stanford.edu/documents/DengBergLiFei-Fei_ECCV2010.pdf). But there seems to be no common consensus on whether or not you should complicate your training. With Neural Nets it might be  better idea to invest more time on the model design rather then data engineering and try to make the network handle everything for you.

Comment: My question is more on, how do I pass the training classification to tensorflow? Currently I pass a one hot encoded vector, which I construct manually. Is that the standard way?

Comment: @AgentX, yes, this is the standard way to do multi-class classification with NN. And there is no reason to worry about large number of classes. It should handle 100K+ classes easily at least from technical perspective. Feel free to opt for `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as @Maxim suggested to allow TF to handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternate way?

Yes, you can work with sparse representations. Your labels will be integer numbers in the range `[0, num_classes-1]` instead of one-hot vectors and you'll need to apply [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) loss function.